# Hide the default keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am pretty new in this programming, I am making a app in Xcode 4.6 with custom keyboard.
I made the keyboard and it is working great but I need to disable the default keyboard when I hit the text box, how do i do that?  Like I said I am new to this so any help would be great.

Comment: i had recently implemented custom keyboard in one of my app using textField.inputView = customKeyBoard. this line automatically hide  defualt keyboard and will show your custom keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have two choices.

**1-** `UITextField` has a delegate methods called

`-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` this is the method when you hit your  `textField`. So you need to hide your default keyboard here.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      [self.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**2-** There is a notification called `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` which is posted immediately to the display of keyboard. So, You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to do your job when you received notification. So, in your `viewDidLoad` method :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

then implement your selector.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(id)sender
{
    [self.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I've tested both of them, i think they are working well.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply, where do i put this code, -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      [self.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
} Im sorry for being so green in this.

Comment: you need to put this where you declare your textfield.Don't forget to set UITextField delegate.

Comment: Thank you very much mstfbsnli, this is working good :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to hide the keyboard or want to show your custom keyboard also? To show your custom keyboard instead of default one, use `inputView` property of textfield and set your keyboard to it. `textField.inputView = customKeyBoard`.